# NI-VISA MessageBasedSession Method to send a Command String followed by Binary Data

Tags: c#, visa

I'm trying to send data to an digital storage oscilloscope using NI-VISA in c#.Net. The data are first received from the DSO using:

```
            MessageBasedSession mbSession;
            MessageBasedSessionWriter writer = new MessageBasedSessionWriter(mbSession);
            MessageBasedSessionReader reader = new MessageBasedSessionReader(mbSession);
            reader.BinaryEncoding = BinaryEncoding.RawLittleEndian;
            writer.BinaryEncoding = BinaryEncoding.RawLittleEndian;
            string loadCommand = ":SYSTem:SETup?";
            mbSession.WriteLine(loadCommand);//edited from .Write() to .WriteLine
            byte[] setupData = reader.ReadBytes(2826);
```

So far so good, and the bytes in setupData are correct.
The problem is sending the data back to the DSO. The only way I can see to do that is using two write methods:

```
            loadCommand = ":SYSTem:SETup ";
            mbSession.Write(loadCommand);
            writer.WriteBinary( setupData);
```

The problem is that it appears the loadCommand and setupData must be sent consecutively, at least that's what it looks like in the documentation:
[Setup Commands for DSO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qflc.jpg)
Also, during unsuccessful trial and erroring, the only time I could get a response from the DSO was when it printed 'file not recognised' on the DSO screen. This was when I tried:

```
      mbSession.Write(loadCommand + strMBRSess);//get 'failed to read file' from DSO
```

Where strMBRSess is the setupData converted to an ASCII string. Trying to send the same data with two write commands got no response from the DSO:

```
            mbSession.Write(loadCommand);
            mbSession.Write(strMBRSess);
```

I am not sure that this can be done by MessageBasedSession, and will be happy for:
1 - a solution of course. 
2 - definite knowledge that it can not be done.
I've had a post on the NI-VISA forum, but did not get any replies.

Things tried after answer by Tom,

```
        writer.WriteBinary(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(":SYSTem:SETup ")); 
        writer.WriteBinary(setupData);//fails-no response

        writer.Write(":SYSTem:SETup ");
        writer.WriteBinary(setupData);//fails-no response      

        writer.WriteLine(":SYSTem:SETup ");
        writer.WriteBinary(setupData);//fails-no response 

        byte[] loadCommandBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(":SYSTem:SETup ");//or....
        byte[] loadCommandBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(":SYSTem:SETup " + Char.MinValue);

        byte[] CombinedCommandData = new byte[loadCommandBytes.Length + setupData.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(loadCommandBytes, 0, CombinedCommandData, 0, loadCommandBytes.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(setupData, 0, CombinedCommandData, loadCommandBytes.Length, setupData.Length);
        writer.WriteBinary(CombinedCommandData);//fails-no response
```

Passing both command and data in the same method will not compile:

```
         writer.WriteBinary(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(":SYSTem:SETup ") + setupData); //operator + cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'byte[]'
```

Have found one post, showing this working. Unfortunately it is not .Net: [Solution for Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8oNE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `mbSession.Write(loadCommand)` is sending a line terminator and that you should not. The VisaNS docs don't say but from my understanding of SCPI your query would have to be terminated and you've said that works, so I conclude [Write(String)](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370627F-01/mstudiowebhelp/html/3c28948c/) sends a line terminator.

Tip: Keep an eye on your instrument's front panel for error messages, if it has one. Sometimes they are better, more timely and easier to see during debugging than error messages retrieved programmatically.

Regardless, this way should work:

```
writer.WriteBinary(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(":SYSTem:SETup "));
writer.WriteBinary(setupData);
```

And, this might:

```
writer.Write(":SYSTem:SETup ");
writer.WriteBinary(setupData);
```

I think you should use methods, such as WriteBinary, Write and WriteLine from MessageBasedSessionWriter if you create one. It looks like methods in MessageBasedSession are for convenience for when you don't need a MessageBasedSessionWriter to write binary.

Comment: Thanks, and I apologise for a mistake in the original post (.Write() should of been .WriteLine()); and it is WriteLine that adds a terminator.  I've added the code tried to the post, unfortunately nothing seems to work, or even elicit a response from the DSO (Rigol DS2072A). Both the working Linux code (see attachment), and the time I got a reponse from the DSO, the string and data were passed in the same write method. If so, then Rigol have not implemented this nicely.